# While publish via Xcode: A downloaded software component is corrupted and will not be used Xcode 12.1

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I got this error while trying to upload the archive to App Store.

[image]

I have followed solutions from https://rb.gy/dipbkg, but I am getting the following error.

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application
```

I am using the macOS Catalina. Any assistance to fix this issue is really appreciatable.